# Angular $watch is not triggering

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-watch

I have a text input with **eonasdan** datetimepicker. There is a **bootstrap** tooltip for that. I want to hide the tooltip when the datetimpicker is active.

There is css class (.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget) when the datetime picker is active. I have tried to get the number of items which has that css class. I got that number also when debugging through the firebug. (I wrote angular directive for datetimepicker and the tooltips)

.jsfile

```
    $scope.noOfDateTimePickers = $('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget').length;

    $scope.$watch('noOfDateTimePickers',function(newValue, oldValue){
      if(newValue>0){
        $('.dateTimePickerToolTips').removeAttr("data-original-titile");
      }else{
        $('.dateTimePickerToolTips').attr("data-original-titile", $scope.message);
      }
    });
```

.html fle

```
<div datetimepicker>
  <a class data-toggle="tooltip" ng-attr-title="{{tooltipMessage}}" tooltip>
    <input type="text" ng-model="startTime">
  </a>
</div>
```

Can someone help me on this, if there is some issue with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that your jQuery call is doing a one-time DOM search which is then stored in your `$scope.noOfDateTimePickers`.  Since that DOM search is one time, your $scope variable is never changing which is never invoking your trigger function.

`$scope.noOfDateTimePickers = $('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget').length //Called once and is never updated`

My recommendation is to find a way to get away from this one-time jQuery call to determine the number of widgets on the page, and instead, have an array of objects which represents your widgets and perform logic based on that object.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you suggest a way how to get the updating value for $scope.noOfDateTimePickers

Comment: Actually, I did not see you stated you made a directive ```datetimepicker```.  Until you share that code, the full issue can't be diagnosed.  Root issue is that you are using a jQuery to query the entire DOM once but then using angular to do 2-way model binding that that one-time value.  The simpler option may be to do a jQuery call everytime you show or hide a datepicker (it exposes those methods)

Comment: Yes Chris, I can hide the tooltip message when call the datetime picker. but cannot re-show the tooltip message since there is no event on datetime piker for that. So I thought above way is fine. :(